# published vars in nested arrays aren't displaying changes

Tags: swiftui

I've got an array (foos) containing another array (bars) that have a published var isExpanded. For each Bar, I want to display an image depending on the state of isExpanded.

My problem lies in that the image does not change when clicking the button that toggles the boolean.

```
class Bar: ObservableObject, Identifiable {
    @Published var isExpanded = false
    var id = UUID()
}

class Foo: ObservableObject, Identifiable {
    @Published var bars:[Bar] = []
    var id = UUID()
}

class FooList: ObservableObject {
    @Published var foos:[Foo] = []

    init(array: [Foo]) {
        foos = array
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var fooList:FooList = createFoos()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(fooList.foos) { foo in
                ForEach(foo.bars) { bar in
                    Button(action: {
                        bar.isExpanded.toggle()
                    }, label: {
                        if bar.isExpanded {
                            Image(systemName: "minus.app")
                        } else {
                            Image(systemName: "plus.app")
                        }
                    })
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

func createFoos() -> FooList {
    var foos = [Foo]()
    for x in 0...5 {
        let foo = Foo()
        for y in 0...5 {
            let bar = Bar()
            foo.bars.append(bar)
        }
        foos.append(foo)
    }
    return FooList(array: foos)
}
```

Unsure if it's related, but I also had to create a third class FooList to hold the array of foos as I could not create an ObservedObject out of an array of objects like:

```
@ObservedObject var fooList:[Foo] = createFoos()
```

Been banging my head against this for a while now and I'm guessing it's some fundamental paradigm that I just don't understand yet. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change model from reference-based to value-based and here is a behaviour which you expect...

Note: with classes it is possible as well, but needs to cross-join updates of internals to external container, which is observed by SwiftUI, so more complex. Changing value at any internal level changes model completely

So, here it is...

[image]

```
struct Bar {
    var isExpanded = false
    var id = UUID()
}

struct Foo {
    var bars:[Bar] = []
    var id = UUID()
}

class FooList: ObservableObject {
    @Published var foos:[Foo] = []

    init(array: [Foo]) {
        foos = array
    }
}

struct TestPublishedModelChanged: View {
    @ObservedObject var fooList:FooList = createFoos()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(Array(fooList.foos.enumerated()), id:\.1.id) { (i, foo) in
                ForEach(Array(foo.bars.enumerated()), id: \.1.id) { (j, bar) in
                    Button(action: {
                        self.fooList.foos[i].bars[j].isExpanded.toggle()
                    }, label: {
                        if self.fooList.foos[i].bars[j].isExpanded {
                            Image(systemName: "minus.square")
                        } else {
                            Image(systemName: "plus.square")
                        }
                    })
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

func createFoos() -> FooList {
    var foos = [Foo]()
    for _ in 0...2 {
        var foo = Foo()
        for _ in 0...2 {
            let bar = Bar()
            foo.bars.append(bar)
        }
        foos.append(foo)
    }
    return FooList(array: foos)
}
```

Comment: thanks. i also had some functions creating the views that I had to change to pass in indices rather than the objects to get it working (that wasn't in the code I posted) but the answer worked. I'm still a bit lost as to what's different than what I had, but I'll take it :)

Comment: The difference is the memory storage/handling that structs and classes do differently...